# Custom cells with textfields and Core Data

Tags: core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview and i made a custom cell with two textfields...i want the text in the textfields to be saved in core data, so i created the core data class for that purpose and i know how to implement the core data methods.

I´m having trouble understanding how can i display the cell in the tableview, so that the user enters the text and then he get´s saved in core data. From my understanding these are the steps:

1 - the tableview loads and displays the custom cell by default with the textfields.

2 - the user enters the text, hits enter and he get´s saved in core data.

My problem is how can i perform number 1, i cannot load data in view did load because there is no data YET!, i have to display the cell first.

Can anyone help me with this issue, let me understand what am i missing here? this is my code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

AppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext=[appDelegate managedObjectContext];


NSError *error;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

}

[self fetchedResultsController];


[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"machines";

cellMeios *cellM = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cellM == nil) {
    cellM = [[cellMeios alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

return cellM;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
{
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

// Create and configure a fetch request.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestMo = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityMo = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Mo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequestMo setEntity:entityMo];

// Create the sort descriptors array.
NSSortDescriptor *cellTitle = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"reference" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:cellTitle, nil];
[fetchRequestMo setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequestMo managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"reference" cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

There are the other methods but i think they are not relevant for my problem, the thing is...i need to display something to the user so that he can fill up!

I already have another tableview working with core data but in that case, the table is supose to be empty at first, then there´s a plus button on the top of the tableview and THEN he choses something and it get´s saved in core data displaying a cell with relevant information.

Thanks in advance
 Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend the table view to be editable, you should have a method like insertNewObject that would be triggered when the user hits the '+' (plus) button in the navigation bar.  The implementation of this method creates a new managed object, inserts it in the context, and reloads the table.  You could also trigger this method when the fetchedResultsController comes back empty.

Here's a version from one of my view controllers:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.managedObject managedObjectContext];
    NSRelationshipDescription *relation = [[self.managedObject entity] relationshipsByName][self.relationship];
    NSEntityDescription *destinationEntity = [relation destinationEntity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = (NSManagedObject*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[destinationEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    if ([relation isOrdered]) {
        [self.items insertObject:newManagedObject atIndex:[self.items count]];
    }
    else {
        NSMutableSet *set = [self.managedObject mutableSetValueForKey:self.relationship];
        [set addObject:newManagedObject];
        self.items = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithSet:set];
    }

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Validation Error", @"Validation Error") message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK") otherButtonTitles: nil, nil] show];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Hello Steven, first of all thank you for answering to my post, i´m really stuck on this one. You say this: "You could also trigger this method when the fetchedResultsController comes back empty"...how could i perform this? I need to reference my cell right? What i want to do is the best approach?

Comment: In essence, for the user to have something to edit, an object has to already exist, then be edited.  This method is an example of inserting a new object in your model and your table, so that it has at least one item.  Implement the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate method controllerDidChangeContent: in your view controller, which will be called when the fetch completes.  If you then find that the fetch returned no results, call insertNewObject directly.  This will reload the table with the new object, most likely before anything shows up on the screen.